# How to make multiple requests from the same IP but different ports (each from different location)

Tags: networking, tcp, portforwarding, ports

I have this scenario: an IP (eg. `192.168.0.109`). It's possible to make some requests from the same IP but thru different ports ? More, each port to be from a different zone. Something like a proxy, but for ports.

So, I would like to achieve something like this:

`192.168.0.109:20000` -> Paris
`192.168.0.109:20457` -> Lyon
`192.168.0.109:21341` -> Sydney

I read something about [TCP Proxy](http://www.partow.net/programming/tcpproxy/index.html) but I am not sure if this is exactly what  I am looking for.

Can anyone explain me if this is achievable and if so, describe me the entire process and what would the steps be in order to have something like this running ?

Comment: Should be asked on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I will also post the question there. Thanks for the head ups

Comment: @Alexander , that's the default.  Provided you don't bind when you create a socket but just "connect" as most applications do, the source port will always be different and random above a certain number.  It needs to be to ensure a unique session each time.

Comment: @Alexander - do not cross post.  Your question is fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each new TCP connection will automatically be assigned a local IP and random port number from the kernel's [`ephemeral ports`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) pool by default. You can optionally [`bind(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) the socket to the desired local IP and/or port before `connect`-ing to the server.  You can `bind()` to a desired IP and let the kernel choose the port for you.

Comment: So, it can be achieved, right ? Could you be nice and add some more details to your given answer ? For example, what will be needed if I want to acheieve this on my own IP Address ? Do I need a VPS ? A VPN ?

Comment: You don't need anything special outside of normal routing to the Internet. I am assuming you are asking about programming side of this. If so, read up on the socket programming. If this is about network/device configuration, then you should move the question to http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Have the client create a `socket` and call `connect` with the details of the server IP:Port.  In this case, the OS automatically provides the local IP:Port to which the client binds to.  This is default behavior.

If you wish, you can have the client bind to a specific IP - call `bind` before `connect`. You can leave the bound Port set to 0 so the OS will still choose a random local Port for you.

Now, when you want to make another connection, simply do the same thing as above. Nothing more is required.

So, you keep creating as many sockets as you want and making connections for them. They will automatically be from the chosen "zones" that they are bound to.

Comment: @Remy, thanks for making my answer much better.